# Unable to read SMART data from internal disks

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I've been trying to read SMART data from my internal drives, but nothing works.

I've used:

- Cristal Disk Info
- GsmartControl
- hd sentinel
- hd tune

None of these programs were able to read SMART data from internal drives (neither M.2 NVME, nor SATA 3), but they are reading it from USB external drives without a problem.

Disks I've used:

- Silicon Power M.2 NVME
- SK Hynix PC711 M.2 NVME
- Toshiba HDWD120 SATA HDD
- WD Green SATA SSD
- HGST SATA HDD

So I guess something is wrong with my system setup.
I've checked my Bios setup and only thing related to SMART is "SMART self test" which was already enabled.

My motherboard is Asus ROG Strix b550-f gaming and I'm using Windows 10 with drivers installed via Windows update. I've also used Armoury crate (app from Asus for managing motherboard and stuff) and it said all drivers are up to date.

**UPDATE**:
I've tried to boot Ubuntu from USB stick, and I was able to read SMART data with Disks utility. So I guess it's a software problem.

**UPDATE 2**:
I've found similar issue online that was caused by StoreMi software. I rememebeer I had installed it some time ago, but removed it. Maybe there are some leftovers that were not removed.

Comment: Try to install (carefully) the [latest BIOS](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b550-f-gaming-model/helpdesk_bios/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that I still had StoreMi driver active after removing the application.
After going into Device manager it was listed under Storage controllers. I've removed all devices and drivers that had StoreMi in it's name, rebooted and... Windows thrown BSOD with unable to access boot media message. I booted once into safe mode without doing anything, restarted and it booted normally with SMART working in all programs.

Comment: Great! If you can now accept your own answer that would be awesome. If you don't bots will keep on bringing this question up.